# Python referencing Construct to it-self

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I wanted to add a referencing table but this does not seem possible.
Do you see a method to avoid this? Or any other suggestions?
I want to define relationships between persons in a family.

```
class Person():
    """
    Person and possibly something we could use as an user.
    """

    RELATIONSHIPS = dict(
        CHILD={
            'opposite': Person.RELATIONSHIPS.PARENT
        },
        PARENT={
            'opposite': Person.RELATIONSHIPS.CHILD
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
class Person():    
    RELATIONSHIPS = dict(CHILD={}, PARENT={})
    RELATIONSHIPS['CHILD']['opposite'] = RELATIONSHIPS['PARENT']
    RELATIONSHIPS['PARENT']['opposite'] = RELATIONSHIPS['CHILD']
```

Note that you can't address them as `Person.RELATIONSHIPS.CHILD.opposite`, but `Person.RELATIONSHIPS['CHILD']['opposite']` and alike.

Or you can use temporary variables:

```
class Person():
    _parent = {}
    _child = {'opposite': _parent}
    _parent['opposite'] = _child
    RELATIONSHIPS = dict(CHILD=_child, PARENT=_parent)
    del _parent, _child
```